# Memcache 1mb limit, how to store over

Tags: php, memcached

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Cache over 1mb memcache alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977676/cache-over-1mb-memcache-alternatives)
>
> [increase item max size in memcached?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795536/increase-item-max-size-in-memcached)
> [Caching a 302MB object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650085/caching-a-302mb-object)

Can anyone tell me how i get around the one mb limit on memcache in php

Getting the below error at the moment:

am getting this with a single image data MemcachePool::set(): Server 127.0.0.1 (tcp 11211, udp 0) failed with: SERVER_ERROR object too large for cache

I am using php and any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Running command line? You can use the `-I` parameter.
Check the wiki, it gives you loads of options and info:
http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewConfiguringServer

You can change the size, but its not recommended, it makes the memory allocation less efficient.

Comment: -m option does not address the question.

Comment: im using php and a compiled memcache dll on windows, any ideas?

Comment: My bad, probably -i then!

Comment: Wrong again, I think. According to the manpage, it should be `-I`.

Comment: @MatthewChambers When you say "php and a compiled memcache dll" you are talking about the client. This is about a command line option you must give to the *server*

Comment: You can change the size with -I on the server, but its not recommended, It makes the memory allocation less efficient.

Comment: so i need to do this with xampp on dev and then on the live server

Comment: should i try serialise first or best to just query the database