# Cache over 1mb memcache alternatives

Tags: php, caching

I have an object in php that is more than one mb. I am using memcache which allows me to store 1mb or data. Does anyone know any other alternatives for data over 1mb. I have read that altering memcache to store more is not the best option.

Comment: The options depend on what you want to store, why you want to store it in memory, how often you need to write, how often you need to read, ...

Comment: Just curios why you have 1MB Object ? They are creative ways to split it into parts

Comment: i have 20k records for images on paging. Rather than query the database each time the site loads

Comment: I think i can come up with a work around .. one moment

Comment: ok thanks let me know most appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [MultipartCache](https://github.com/olekukonko/MultipartCache) which extends `memcache` to support data higher than `1MB limit`. Please note that in `memcached 1.4.2` and higher you can configure the maximum supported object size by using the -I command-line option.

```
 memcached -I 5m     //default: 1mb, min: 1k, max: 128m
```

[MultipartCache](https://github.com/olekukonko/MultipartCache) simply splits the data into different parts based on the  limit set  `max 1MB`

**Example:**

```
$largeSet = range(0, 100000);
$key = "largeSet";

$cache = new MultipartCache();
$cache->setLimit(1024);
$cache->set($key, $largeSet);
```

The system would split the data base on `size/limit` which is about `575` different places for the sample above.

To get this information is pretty easy

```
$dataFromCache = $cache->get($key);
```

How are we sure that the the data is ok ? that is what the `hash` is for but lets do a random test

```
for($i = 0; $i < 20; $i ++) {
    $rand = mt_rand(0, 100000);
    printf("%s - %s\n", $dataFromCache[$rand], assert($dataFromCache[$rand] == $rand) ? "true" : "false");
}
```

Output

```
39603 - true
16034 - true
23116 - true
94038 - true
64481 - true
84987 - true
53912 - true
32153 - true
43965 - true
71144 - true
97309 - true
53227 - true
28525 - true
9936 - true
16921 - true
27323 - true
35129 - true
46235 - true
5641 - true
43425 - true
```

Now lets look at more sensitive information .. like an image ...

```
$key = "largeImage";
$cache = new MultipartCache();
$cache->addserver("127.0.0.1");
$cache->set($key, file_get_contents("large_image.jpg"));

header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
echo $cache->get($key);
```

Comment: I would keep on improving it  ... you can also add [Add Issues](https://github.com/olekukonko/MultipartCache/issues) if any ...